# Kinect: How to get the skeleton data from some depth data( geting from kinect but i modified some place)

Tags: kinect, depth

I could get the depth frame from my Kinect and then modify data in the frame.
Now I want to use the modified depth frame to get the skeleton data.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

well, I find there's no way to do this with microsoft kinect sdks. Now, I find its ok to use OpenNI, an open sourse  API by Primesense.